# Fill down empty values with conditions in SAS

Tags: sas, fill

How do I fill down empty values for different groups. 
My data looks like:

```
id visit status    var reason 
1   1     Done     x1
1   1     Done     x2  
1   1     Done     x3 
1   2     Not Done x1  text1 
1   2     Not Done x2   
1   2     Not Done x3  
1   3     Done     x1
1   3     Done     x2  
1   3     Done     x3   
2   1     Not Done x1  text2 
2   1     Not Done x2   
2   1     Not Done x3  
2   2     Done     x1
2   2     Done     x2  
2   2     Done     x3  
2   3     Done     x1
2   3     Done     x2  
2   3     Done     x3
```

The output should be like this

```
id visit status    var reason 
1   1     Done     x1
1   1     Done     x2  
1   1     Done     x3 
1   2     Not Done x1  text1 
1   2     Not Done x2  text1
1   2     Not Done x3  text1
1   3     Done     x1
1   3     Done     x2  
1   3     Done     x3   
2   1     Not Done x1  text2 
2   1     Not Done x2  text2 
2   1     Not Done x3  text2
2   2     Done     x1
2   2     Done     x2  
2   2     Done     x3  
2   3     Done     x1
2   3     Done     x2  
2   3     Done     x3
```

I think this is a quite simple problem, but for now, I haven't been able to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Umm. From the example it seem you could do: if status='Done' then reason= 'text'. However it seems that you wish to have reason filled if category has single entity of text. If so, please lay out the rules how you wish to fill.

Comment: I modified my question little bit. So I want that reason (not done) to be same with all variables for one subject for one visit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple task utilising the `first.variable` functionality that exists in a data step when a `by` statement is used.

Essentially I've created a new variable that is assigned the value of Reason whenever a new visit is encountered.  The `retain` statement ensures that the new variable value is copied for all subsequent rows where the Id and Visit do not change.  Then I just delete the original Reason variable and rename the new one.

```
data have;
infile datalines dsd;
input id visit status &$ var $ reason $;
datalines;
1,   1,     Done,     x1,,
1,   1,     Done,     x2,, 
1,   1,     Done,     x3,, 
1,   2,     Not Done, x1,  text1,
1,   2,     Not Done, x2,,   
1,   2,     Not Done, x3,,  
1,   3,     Done,     x1,,
1,   3,     Done,     x2,,  
1,   3,     Done,     x3,,   
2,   1,     Not Done, x1,  text2, 
2,   1,     Not Done, x2,,   
2,   1,     Not Done, x3,,  
2,   2,     Done,     x1,,
2,   2,     Done,     x2,,  
2,   2,     Done,     x3,,  
2,   3,     Done,     x1,,
2,   3,     Done,     x2,,  
2,   3,     Done,     x3  
;
run;

data want;
set have;
retain reason_new;
by id visit;
if first.visit then reason_new=reason;
drop reason;
rename reason_new = reason;
run;
```